# Docker DB connection refused

Tags: database-connection, docker

I have fedora 20 running in my container, I can start my container and point it to a specific port through docker and the Websphere Liberty page loads just fine. (which is what i have in it). However, in the same container i have my db connection string- i can ping it fine, but in the logs when the wlp service start it throws db connection exception- cant connect. Maybe i ned to expose a port that db is running on? not sure, or maybe I am doing something completely wrong? I just got Dockers and dont have much experience with it...any help would be great! thanks!

Comment: Where is the database running?  In the same container?  In another container?  On the host?

Comment: I am trying to connect to my DB smoke env. The db connection string points to our smoke env.

Comment: So the DB is running on another machine entirely?  Docker doesn't need any port mapping for that. Is the name resolved - can you ping the DB host from inside a container?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container, Docker has two methods of assigning ports on the Docker host:

- Docker can randomly assign a high port from the range 49000 to 49900
  on the Docker host that maps to port 80 on the container.
- You can specify a specific port on the Docker host that maps to port
  80 on    the container.

This will open a random port on the Docker host that will connect to port 80 on
the Docker container.

The -p flag manages which network ports Docker exposes at runtime.

`$ sudo docker ps -l` command will let you view the Docker port mapping.

Comment: if i do command 'docker port' with the port i mapped it shows the mapping on 49154, but still no idea

Comment: Here is a good link explaining the steps needed for a dockerfile for MongoDB image in Fedora 20 http://cloud-mechanic.blogspot.ie/2014/08/docker-simple-service-container-example.html

Comment: hey sorry if i m getting this wrong, but seems like they are installing MongoDB? I shouldnt have to do that right...I am simply trying to point to my Smoke env DB. I can ping that ip too..but in the logs is says cannot connect

Comment: Do a sudo docker inspect <container> and post result

Comment: root@localhost ~]# docker inspect 7c99fba71e4f0a8c11677feae83eb39fe61f9cd3feb352f660d3bd8be763d718
[{
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "Args": [],
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],

Comment: "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "11339/tcp": {}
        },
        "Hostname": "7c99fba71e4f",
        "Image": "docker/mike_trying",
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "PortSpecs": null,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Tty": true,
        "User": "",
        "Volumes": null,

Comment: },
    "Created": "2014-12-15T19:13:30.994040081Z",
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "Links": null,
        "LxcConf": [],
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,

Comment: "RestartPolicy": {
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
            "Name": ""
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null
    },
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7c99fba71e4f0a8c11677feae83eb39fe61f9cd3feb352f660d3bd8be763d718/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7c99fba71e4f0a8c11677feae83eb39fe61f9cd3feb352f660d3bd8be763d718/hosts",
    "Id": "7c99fba71e4f0a8c11677feae83eb39fe61f9cd3feb352f660d3bd8be763d718",
    "Image": "a24a3514f9c34fed23c6504a4d74ace725615dc1ad74140b52a6131ca74e4878",
    "MountLabel": "",

Comment: "Name": "/trusting_jones",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": null
    },
    "Path": "/bin/bash",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7c99fba71e4f0a8c11677feae83eb39fe61f9cd3feb352f660d3bd8be763d718/resolv.conf",

Comment: Can you do sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' <containerNmae> so we can see that the container has an IP address

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' dff57157b86939dbdab272ec5638f74649ea503513fe0d2cad69a3a41c5b24b6 
172.17.0.2

Comment: Just an update,i deleted all the old containers and imgages, and created this one fresh.